# Unique constraint Ignored while saving child entity in mysql hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables. Consider them as below. Person has `OneToMany` relationship with Phone.

```
create table Person(
  id varchar,
  name varchar
);

create table Phone(
  id varchar,
  name varchar,
  person_id varchar,
  UNIQUE KEY `unq` (`name`)
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES Person(id)
);
```

Now Java Code looks as below.

```
Person person = new Person();
Phone phone = new Phone();
phone.setPerson(person);
phoneRepository.save(phone);
```

Query ignores unique constraint on the child table while insertion. It is saving multiple duplicate entries

What seems to be causing issue? Is it expected behavior?

Comment: is tables created by hibernate or  you did manually.

Comment: Are the duplicated values for NAME column all `NULL`s?

Comment: @AngadBansode Manually. Existing table introducing it as child table.

Comment: @dbl No it is not.

Comment: Then the foreign key is not present in the table definition. You can easily check this by executing the following query `describe Phone;`.

Comment: @dbl It is present I had modified the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store existing Person entity

Instead to instantiate a new entity

```
Person person = new Person();
```

try to read existing entity

```
Person existingPerson = personRepository.findOneByName(name);
```

and set the existing entity to your phone

```
phoneRepository.save(existingPerson)
```

Comment: I just provided example. Actual, I am using the existing entity. This no where solves my problem.

Comment: the example doesn't use and existing entity but it creates a new one